# PowerShell gaps in output

Tags: powershell, console, output

When I run two commands one after the other in a script, I often end up with big gaps, as you can see with these two commands (I've concatenated them with ";" so can see the issue as a one-liner, it's just a `Get-Netipaddress` followed by a `gwmi`) they end up with a three line gaps between them. Sometimes I want more compact information in my output. Is there a way to tell PowerShell to stop introducing huge gaps between output?

```
Get-Netipaddress | where AddressFamily -eq IPv4 | select IPAddress,InterfaceIndex,InterfaceAlias | sort InterfaceIndex ; gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, VolumeName, @{n="Size(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

Comment: Adding commands in one line separated by ; doesnt make the command a single command.. it still is two statements just in one line. If there is blank lines from the output, you'll see the gaps

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, but I'm not sure I recommend it because it ruins your ability to further process any of the originally returned objects.

```
($(Get-Netipaddress | Where AddressFamily -eq IPv4 | Select IPAddress,InterfaceIndex,InterfaceAlias | Sort InterfaceIndex ; gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, VolumeName, @{n="Size(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}) | Out-String) -replace '(?m)^\r?\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always also the option of writing a format function yourself.
Something like the below perhaps:

```
function Format-TableCompact {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)] 
        [PsObject]$InputObject,

        [switch]$AppendNewline
    )
    # If the data is sent through the pipeline, use $input to collect is as array
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $InputObject = @($Input) }
    # or use : $InputObject = $Input | ForEach-Object { $_ }

    $result = ($InputObject | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim()
    if($AppendNewline) { $result += [Environment]::NewLine }
    $result
}
```

This will output the object as table without any leading or trailing newlines, so called using

```
Get-Netipaddress | where AddressFamily -eq IPv4 | select IPAddress,InterfaceIndex,InterfaceAlias | sort InterfaceIndex | Format-TableCompact
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, VolumeName, @{n="Size(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}} | Format-TableCompact
```

it will slam both tables directly against eachother.

In this case however I would opt for having at least one newline gap between the tables so I would use the `-AppendNewline` switch on the first table to output:

```
Get-Netipaddress | where AddressFamily -eq IPv4 | select IPAddress,InterfaceIndex,InterfaceAlias | sort InterfaceIndex | Format-TableCompact -AppendNewline
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, VolumeName, @{n="Size(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}} | Format-TableCompact
```